# Not able to launch browser using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to inherit browser class in test. Can someone please point out what am i doing wrong here. I am new to python

This is my test class where I am trying to inherit browser class

```
import unittest
from Configurations.Browser import Browser
class GoogleTest(Browser):
    def test_homepage(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").send_keys("Test")
```

Browser.py:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
class Browser(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executablepath=r"C:\Setups\Selenium\Drivers\geckodriver.exe")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    def tearDown(self):
        if(self.driver != None):
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.quit()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the "excutablepath" to "executable_path".(Browser.py)

like this

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Setups\Selenium\Drivers\geckodriver.exe")
```